# unable to allocate hugepages for an application, rocky linux 9

Tags: huge-pages

In earlier systems (CentOS 8) I was able to make an application run using huge pages for memory allocations by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to libhugetlbfs.so.
I tried the same approach in Rocky Linux 9. However there is no libhugetlbfs package for el9. Instead I installed successfully an rpm I had for el8 (libhugetlbfs-2.21-17.el8.x86_64.rpm).

I tried running the binary as before:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libhugetlbfs.so ./brhclus <args>
```

However looking in /proc/meminfo as the program runs, I see no reserved huge pages

```
AnonPages:      52018332 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:   614400
HugePages_Free:    614400
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:        1258291200 kB
```

System

```
OS: Rocky Linux 9.2
Kernel: 5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2.x86_64
Memory 1.5T
```

I may be missing something obvious - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found why this doesn't work. libhugetlbfs uses __morecore function in glibc which has been removed (?) or at least deprecated.
As a solution I use transparent huge pages systemwide enabled using

```
echo always > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

I consider my question answered.